# Output Mode for SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

SQLite shell supports csv, column, list and a few other [output modes](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html).

The line output mode comes in handy while exploring database. I was wondering does anybody know whether SQL Server Management Studio, natively or through some addin, supports similar output mode or not.

[image: SQLite line mode]

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the `Results to Text` option in the query window (also achieved by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). This will return a result set like this:

```
CustomerID  CompanyName                 ContactName   ...
----------- --------------------------  ------------- ...
GREAL       Great Lakes Food Market     Howard Snyder ...
HUNGC       Hungry Coyote Import Store  Yoshi Latimer ...
```

This may help you accomplish the same thing, that is, something that "comes in handy while exploring database".